# gets() and getchar() are being ignored

Tags: c, recursion, getchar

I'm new here and with c coding, so please try to be patience with me.

My issue is getting char input both using getchar() and scanf(" %c") for recursive call.

The compiler ignoring the getchar(), and outs '\n' rather than waiting for a character.

issued line: pfile->content.folder.files[i] = newFile(getchar());

preventing me to create the sub-files/folders...
The function newFile should create a folder or a file (a text file), and in case it is a folder, I should 
provide the number of files inside the folder, and there is the recursive call to create the files inside the folder already created.

```
typedef struct {
    char *name;                 //name of File
    char type;                  // 'f' - data file, 'd'-folder.
    union {
        char data[81];             //f -80 chars array for content of file.
        struct {                //d -arry of pointers to 'File' Files.
            struct File ** files;
            unsigned int size;
        }folder;
    }content;
}File;
```

The function:

```
FILE * newFile(char type){
    File *pfile = (File*)malloc(sizeof(File)); //creating new File
    if (type != 'f' && type != 'd') { // in case of wrong input of type.
        printf("Wrong input!\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    //File *pfile = (File*)malloc(sizeof(File)); //creating new File
    printf("Enter File name: ");
    scanf(" %s", &pfile->name);// Name of new File

    if (type == 'f') {      // New File is 'folder'
        printf("Enter number of files in folder '%s': ",&pfile->name);
        scanf(" %d", &pfile->content.folder.size);
        if (pfile->content.folder.size == 0) { // Zero files in the folder
            pfile->content.folder.files[pfile->content.folder.size - 1] = NULL; // No more files / empty folder
        }
        pfile->content.folder.files = (File**)malloc(pfile->content.folder.size * sizeof(File));

        for (int i = 0; i < pfile->content.folder.size; ++i) { // creates 'size' file per folder
            printf("Enter type of %d file(d-folder,f-file): ", i + 1);
            pfile->content.folder.files[i] = newFile(getchar());  //<<<<<=====ISSUE HERE !
        }
        return pfile;

    }
    else /*if (type == 'd')*/ { //File creation
        printf("Enter file's text:\n");
        scanf(" %s",&pfile->content.data);
    }
    return pfile;   
}
```

I'll appreciate any idea or improvement suggestions.

Dan.

Comment: Is `File` the same as `FILE`? `pfile->content.folder.files = (File**)malloc(pfile->content.folder.size * sizeof(File));` should be `sizeof(File*)`. Also do not cast result of malloc. Please create an [MCVE]. Please post `File` definition.  What does it mean that "compiler is ignoring something", how do you "detect" that? What did you expect to happen, what did not happen? Is `-1` in `pfile->content.folder.files[pfile->content.folder.size - 1] = NULL`  a valid index in `pfile->content.folder.files`? What is the source of `newFile`?

Comment: 1.FILE was a mistake, thank you for that. there is a structure 'File'.
2.fixed malloc line.
3.To be specific, after getchar() in the mentioned line, the value sent was '\n', without asking me to enter a character as I expected.
4.typedef struct {
 char *name;     //name of File
 char type;     // 'f' - data file, 'd'-folder.
 union {
  char data[81];             //f -80 chars array for content of file.
  struct {                //d -arry of pointers to 'File' Files.
   struct File ** files;
   unsigned int size;
  }folder;
 }content;
}File;
5.What do you mean by "source"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calls to `scanf` leave a newline in the input buffer.  Other calls to `scanf` using `%d` and `%s` skips over whitespace when reading.  `getchar` however reads the next character in the buffer which happens to be that newline character.

Instead, use `scanf` with the format string `" %c"`.  The `%c` format specifier doesn't skip whitespace, but the leading space does.

```
char newtype;
scanf(" %c", &newtype);
pfile->content.folder.files[i] = newFile(newtype);
```

Comment: I'll try that and let you know.
I've got a consultation about using fseek function. Do you think it can help in any way?

Comment: @DanShar You should create a separate question for that.

Comment: NVM,  it works great after adding fseek(stdin; 0 ,SEEK_END).